# How can I find all subnodes in my XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to get all subpages in my example below. The XML looks like this(simple layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<main> 
  <group  title="Server Tools" enabled="True">
    <page title="Server Tools" pageId="1" subtitle="Tools for servers" enabled="True">
      <subpage title="Name-1" pageId="2" subtitle="" enabled="True">        
        <subpage title="Name-2" pageId="3" subtitle="" enabled="True">
            <subpage title="Name-3" pageId="4" subtitle="" enabled="True">
                <subpage title="Name-4" pageId="5" subtitle="" enabled="True">                  
                </subpage>
            </subpage>
        </subpage>
      </subpage>
    </page> 
  </group>
</main>
```

I have tried to create the following, but it only finds the first "subpage".

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path + @"\config.xml");

XmlNodeList groups = doc.SelectNodes("main/group");
foreach (XmlNode group in groups)
{
    String groupTitle = group.Attributes["title"].InnerText;
    String groupEnabled = group.Attributes["enabled"].InnerText;
    maxResults = Convert.ToInt32(group.Attributes["maxResults"].InnerText);

    if (groupEnabled == "True")
    {
       firstGroup.Title = groupTitle;
       XmlNodeList pages = group.SelectNodes("page");

       foreach (XmlNode page in pages)
       {
          String pageTitle = page.Attributes["title"].InnerText;
          int pageId = Convert.ToInt32(page.Attributes["pageId"].InnerText);
          String subtitle = page.Attributes["subtitle"].InnerText;
          String pageEnabled = page.Attributes["enabled"].InnerText;

          if(pageEnabled == "True")
          {
             firstGroup.Items.Add(new PageItem(pageId, pageTitle, subtitle));
             pageList.Add(pageId);
             XmlNodeList subpages = page.SelectNodes("subpage");

             foreach (XmlNode subpage in subpages)
             {
                string subpageTitle = subpage.Attributes["title"].InnerText;
                int subpageId = Convert.ToInt32(subpage.Attributes["pageId"].InnerText);
                String subpageSubtitle = subpage.Attributes["subtitle"].InnerText;
                String subpageEnabled = subpage.Attributes["enabled"].InnerText;

                if (subpageEnabled == "True")
                {
                   subpageDic.Add(subpageId, new Tuple<int, string, string>(pageId, subpageTitle, subpageSubtitle));
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to go through all subpage(s) below subpage and get the attributes available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem probably is that the subpages are nested.

Comment: Try tu use recursion to loop through nested subpages.

Comment: Hi Krizz, Hmm okay, is there an easier way to do this layout then. I want to be able to have mulitple page nodes and subpages, but one subpage should also have sub, sub, sub page if needed. Any ideas ;)

Comment: pistipanko, do you have an example you could add to help me in my current code example :) thx in advance

Comment: @cptrico chceck my latest answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is here**:

```
XmlNodeList subpages = page.SelectNodes("subpage");
```

`subpages` contains only the children `subpage` elements of the element contained in `page`.

However, you want all *descendants* of `page`.

**Solution**:

**Replace the above line with this**:

```
XmlNodeList subpages = page.SelectNodes(".//subpage");
```

The variable `subpages` now contains all `subpage` descendants of the current node `page`.

Comment: Thanks for the very clean answer, this is your problem, this is how you fix it, I like this. Thank you. It is now working as I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try with XPATH:

```
XmlDocument document = ...;
var nodes = document.SelectNodes("//subpage");
```

`nodes` will contain this collection:

```
<subpage title="Name-1" pageId="2" subtitle="" enabled="True">        
    <subpage title="Name-2" pageId="3" subtitle="" enabled="True">
        <subpage title="Name-3" pageId="4" subtitle="" enabled="True">
                <subpage title="Name-4" pageId="5" subtitle="" enabled="True">                  
                </subpage>
            </subpage>
        </subpage>
    </subpage>
<subpage title="Name-2" pageId="3" subtitle="" enabled="True">
    <subpage title="Name-3" pageId="4" subtitle="" enabled="True">
    <subpage title="Name-4" pageId="5" subtitle="" enabled="True">                  
</subpage>
```

Now, for each node in nodes select recursively `//subpage`.

EDIT:

XPATH is a powerful tool. Try with this xpath: `//../subpage`. The result is:

```
<subpage title="Name-1" pageId="2" subtitle="" enabled="True">        
        <subpage title="Name-2" pageId="3" subtitle="" enabled="True">
            <subpage title="Name-3" pageId="4" subtitle="" enabled="True">
                <subpage title="Name-4" pageId="5" subtitle="" enabled="True">                  
                </subpage>
            </subpage>
        </subpage>
    </subpage>
-----------------------
<subpage title="Name-2" pageId="3" subtitle="" enabled="True">
    <subpage title="Name-3" pageId="4" subtitle="" enabled="True">
        <subpage title="Name-4" pageId="5" subtitle="" enabled="True">                  
        </subpage>
    </subpage>
</subpage>
-----------------------
<subpage title="Name-3" pageId="4" subtitle="" enabled="True">
    <subpage title="Name-4" pageId="5" subtitle="" enabled="True">                  
    </subpage>
</subpage>
-----------------------
<subpage title="Name-4" pageId="5" subtitle="" enabled="True">
</subpage>
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples :) very help full.

Answer (score 0):

Forget XMLDocument and use LINQ to XML instead.  Once you have loaded up the document using `XDocument.Load()`, you can use code like

```
IEnumerable<XElement> de=
    from el in xmlTree.Descendants("subpage")
    select el;
    foreach (XElement el in de)
Console.WriteLine(el.Attributes("title"), el.Attributes("pageID"));//etc
```

Comment: This will only get the top-level `subpage` elements (4, using the example) and not **all** of them (10, again from the example).

Comment: No, I suppose it returns all the subpage elements, including the top-level ones. It doesn't get information about associated page element, but when looking at the code snippet in the question, I'm not sure if it's needed.

Comment: No, it returns *all* the subpage elements.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx .  And it's a hell of a lot easier than any of the other code I've seen posted here :-)

Comment: Thanks for the examples, maybe I will change to LINQ later on.. ;-)

Comment: Well, if you found it useful then please give my comment an upvote.  Ever since I converted to LINQ I've never looked back.  It's *so* much easier than DOM or XPath based methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
        string path = @"..\LinqToXml\LinqToXml\config.Xml";

        XElement doc2 = XElement.Load(path);

         var element = from t in doc2.Elements("group").Elements("page").Descendants() select t;

        foreach (var el in element)
        {
            if (el.HasAttributes)
            {
                foreach (var att in el.Attributes())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(att.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're selecting *everything* with this - not just the `subpage` elements.

Comment: Thanks for all your quick replies. Do you think it will be better to change my xml to something else if it is difficult to do nested. Or ? just need to be able to support multiple sublevels. (yuck) do you have a idea on what i should do to get it all parsed. :)

Comment: Stick with your format and see my answer on using LINQ to XML.  It will work, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

Once converted to an XElement, you can make use of the [`XPathSelectElements` extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) method along with a '//' to select all elements with a specific name.

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

...

var path = "<Your path>";
var doc = XElement.Load(path);

var subPages = doc.XPathSelectElements("//subpage[@pageId != '']")
                  .Select(x => new
                               {
                                   Id = Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("pageId").Value,
                                   SubTitle = x.Attribute("subtitle").Value,
                                   Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(x.Attribute("enabled").Value)
                               }
                  )
                  .ToDictionary(u => u.Id, u => new Tuple<int, string, string>(u.Id, u.SubTitle, u.Enabled)
```

Comment: NOTE: Was a little unsafe there with assumptions that "subtitle" and "enabled" attributes exist in the XML too and did not safely confirm that "pageId" and "enabled" attribute values parse to expected types. Will leave that part up to you...